# Manually Triggering jQuery.validate before saving

Tags: jquery-validate

I have a save button (input button) that I have written javascript code to save the form data to the database. My jQuery .validate function doesn't run before I save the form. How can I manually execute my jQuery .validate function before I save. Here is what I am doing.

```
<input type="button" class="saveSubmit" name="action" value="Save" />

// Give user feedback when clicking save
$(".saveSubmit").click(function() {
    if (save() == true) {
        alert("Email has been saved.");
    } else {
        alert("Error saving email.");
    };
    return false;
});

// Validation
$("#emailForm").validate({ 
    // rules here 
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found it. I need to use `$("#emailForm").valid()`.

Comment: @Mike-if you place the validation section inside a $document.ready() it will execute automatically.

Comment: I do and it wasn't triggering.

Comment: I've used the validate plugin a lot and have had no such issues. Maybe if you post the original code (for auto trigger) I can track down the issue.

Comment: Just what I needed. Couldn't understand why `$("#form").validate()` wouldn't work. It's useful if you want to set some onclick on your submit button since it disables the automatic triggering of validate (at least it did for me)